# How to use 'reduce' function to filter and display products in cart

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

I am trying to train myself with Javascript and am a bit confused with `reduce` and would appreciate some guidance in understanding it. I've done a lot of research and have arrived at a stage where some clarity beyond just googling is needed. So here's my basic sample code..

the ids are the cart ids and the products are the products in a store

```
      const ids = [4, 3, 1];
      const products = [
        { id: 1, product: "Product 1" },
        { id: 2, product: "Product 2" },
        { id: 3, product: "Product 3" },
        { id: 4, product: "Product 4" },
        { id: 5, product: "Product 5" },
        { id: 6, product: "Product 6" },
        { id: 7, product: "Product 7" },
      ];
```

I need to display the products which are in the cart so I went with 3 options
The `for` loop, the `map` and `filter` and finally the `reduce`

---

**FOR LOOP**

```
      // SOLUTION WITH FOR LOOP
      const selectedProducts = [];
      for (id of ids) {
        const selectedProduct = products.filter((product) => product.id === id);
        selectedProducts.push(selectedProduct);
      }
      console.log("selectedProducts", selectedProducts);
```

**Question 1** : Currently I have just 7 products. but in an actual store there would be thousands of products. So is filtering thousands of products for each id a good idea. Is there a better way to do this?

---

**MAP and FILTER**

```
      // SOLUTION WITH MAP
      const mappedProducts = ids.map((id) => {
        const [obj] = products.filter((product) => product.id === id);
        return obj;
      });
      console.log("mappedProducts", mappedProducts);
```

**Question 2** : As filter creates an array I ended up with an array of arrays and had to destructure the array and return the object. Is there a better way where I could directly destructure/pass the object without explicitly declaring return.

---

**REDUCE**

```
      // SOLUTION WITH REDUCE
      const initialArray = [];
      const reducedProducts = products.reduce(function (acc, product) {
        const productId = product.id;
        if (ids.includes(product.id)) acc.push(product);
        return acc;
      }, initialArray);

      console.log("reducedProducts", reducedProducts);
      console.log("initialArray", initialArray);
```

**Question 3** : What am I doing wrong with reduce?

This is my first time with reduce and I am sure I am doing something wrong here.. as reduce is supposed to be more compact than the `for` and `map`-`filter` combination but in my case it seems to be the opposite. Also I thought that with reduce the initialValue does not get mutated. But in my case it is getting mutated.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is filtering thousands of products for each id a good idea. Is there a better way to do this?

From the `products` array, allow for easy lookup by restructuring it into an object or map indexed by ID, so you just need to use ordinary bracket notation or `.get` to get the matching object (`O(1)`).

```js
const ids = [4, 3, 1];
const products = [
  { id: 1, product: "Product 1" },
  { id: 2, product: "Product 2" },
  { id: 3, product: "Product 3" },
  { id: 4, product: "Product 4" },
  { id: 5, product: "Product 5" },
  { id: 6, product: "Product 6" },
  { id: 7, product: "Product 7" },
];
const productsById = Object.fromEntries(products.map(
  obj => [obj.id, obj]
));
const result = ids.map(id => productsById[id]);
console.log(result);
```

> Is there a better way where I could directly destructure/pass the object without explicitly declaring return.

You could `.find` instead, which returns the matching object instead of returning an array - but that's still an `O(n ^ 2)` process. Indexing each product by its ID is better.

> as reduce is supposed to be more compact than the for and map-filter combination but in my case it seems to be the opposite. Also I thought that with reduce the initialValue does not get mutated. But in my case it is getting mutated.

Not at all - `.reduce`, when not used in the appropriate circumstance, is indeed more verbose than more standard loops, as you're seeing. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg).

> Also I thought that with reduce the initialValue does not get mutated.

Sure it can, if the initial value is an object (and not a primitive) - objects can be mutated. If you mutate the accumulator parameter and return it, the next iteration (and the next, and the final return value) is the same exact object.

Comment: I would suggest `new Map` instead of `Object.fromEntries`. The object solution will coerce the ids into strings whereas the Map accepts any value as a key.

Comment: @CertainPerformance : the explanation really helped and the video link was really helpful.. hearing someone with 20 years of javascript experience say that he'd like to write code that would be readable and probably resemble the way a beginner would probably write instead of complicating code was nice to know..:-)..

Answer (score 1):

Just for note, a couple of examples with high-order functions:

**reduce**

```
products.reduce((acc, product) => {
    if (ids.includes(product.id)) acc.push(product);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

**filter**

```
products.filter((product) => ids.includes(product.id));
// or with destructuring 
products.filter(({ id }) => ids.includes(id));
```

**map and flat**

```
products.map((product) => (ids.includes(product.id)) ? product : []).flat();
```

**flatMap**

```
products.flatMap((product) => (ids.includes(product.id)) ? product : []);
```